# Why does Archer say "Balls" whenever someone says "Benoit"?

Tags: dialogue, archer

In series 2 of ***Archer*** in the episode where they go to Monaco, there is a hotel manager called Benoit. Whenever Benoit says his own name, or someone else says it, Archer immediately says "Balls".

I think I'm missing the joke. Why does Archer say that?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Benoit** is a French name pronounced like **Ben Wa**. When Benoit tells his name to Archer, he laughs because it reminds him of [Ben Wa Balls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Wa_balls), a sex toy.

[Source 1](http://archer.wikia.com/wiki/Benoit)

> As the Gran Prix was going on, Benoit checked Malory Archer, Sterling Archer, Lana Kane, and Ray Gillette into a nearby hotel. When Archer asks him his name, Benoit tells him his name, only for Archer to laugh, since it reminds him of Ben Wa Balls, a sex toy.

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Benoit%20Balls)

> **Archer:** Sounds like 'Ben Wa Balls,' Benoit... Balls. See? You can't even say it without saying 'Balls.'
>
> **Archer:** Hang on! Benoit Balls!

[Transcripts](http://archerexplained.com/season-2/s02e11-jeu-monegasque/)

Comment: It takes a deep knowledge of esoterica to keep up with Archer.

Comment: Right, I'm just saying, you say that's a mispronunciation but I do not believe that it is. FWIW, the IPA for the name is ​"[bənwa]".

Comment: @BoundaryImposition And what's the correct pronunciation of "ben wa"?

Comment: Benoit isn't actually pronounced like Ben Wa. It would be the closest an English person might be able to pronounce it, but in french it would be closer to B - the "U" sound from *Murder* - N - wa as in waaaaa (think of a low, crying sound) but cut short. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Touché. Well, this is why we have IPA! Anyway I'm not aware that the pronunciation of "Ben Wa" substantially varies across the English-speaking world, though I suppose I wouldn't be surprised if the scousers managed to mess it up ;)

Comment: @Fred: You're right about the pronunciation of "Benoit" in French, but that same French person will also pronounce "ben wa" the same way they pronounce "Benoit". So it seems that within the same language, a person is liable to pronounce both the same way.